# Change font size of HeatMap annotations

Tags: matlab, fonts, heatmap

When using HeatMap() in MatLab I cannot change the font size in the figure properties editor.  Is there a way to modify the font size? The default is much too small.  Here is what I have:

% normal = my 3x3 data matrix

```
HM_normal = HeatMap(normal, 'Colormap', jet, 'Annotate', true, 'AnnotPrecision', 3);
plot(HM_normal)
```

This outputs a heat map annotated with numbers much too small.  There isn't anything on here, Google, or elsewhere I can find on modifying the annotation size in HeatMap()

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please read ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the instructions on how to format your question such as putting in code blocks. Also tag your question properly: this is a question about matlab far more than it is about fonts. Also note that the code you show does not have anything relating to font switching, so: what have you already tried? Have you looked for any help by searching the matlab documentation, google, as well as stackoverflow, before asking this question? What did you find, and how did that not solve your specific problem?

Comment: Sorry I hit 'ask' too soon and couldn't find how to edit my question but I see now